# Django pipeliner: /usr/bin/env: yuicompressor: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, yui-compressor, django-pipeline

I have the following versions of django and django-pipeline:

```
Django==1.10.3
django-pipeline==1.6.9
```

In /usr/bin/ I see "yui-compresssor" listed. Running collectstatic gives the following error.

```
pipeline.exceptions.CompressorError: /usr/bin/env: yuicompressor: No such file or directory
```

When I run my site with debug set to false it loads OK, but when debug is false I just get a 500 error page so the problem is when it is trying to compress the assets.

On my production settings file I have...

```
PIPELINE['CSS_COMPRESSOR'] = 'pipeline.compressors.yui.YUICompressor'
PIPELINE['JS_COMPRESSOR'] = 'pipeline.compressors.yui.YUICompressor'
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: `yui-compresssor != yuicompressor`. If your script name don't match this is expectable.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. From pipeline docs I see you can set "YUI_BINARY". So on my production settings file I added "YUI_BINARY = '/usr/bin/env yui-compressor'". But when I run collectstatic it gives same error ie still looks for yuicompressor rather then yui-compresssor.

Comment: Why there is three `s` in `yui-compresssor`?

Comment: Sorry I typed that response by hand so must have been a typo. Copied and pasted directly from my settings file I have "YUI_BINARY = '/usr/bin/env yui-compressor'"

Comment: Can you add output of this command `ls -la /usr/bin/yui*`

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 258 Jan 17  2010 /usr/bin/yui-compressor

Comment: Try creating symlink `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/yui-compressor  /usr/bin/yuicompressor`

Comment: That did the job, collectstatic is working now. Thanks a million!

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
YUI_BINARY = '/usr/bin/yui-compressor'
```

Because `'/usr/bin/env yui-compressor'` is not path to binary

Another way to fix this is to create symlink

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/yui-compressor /usr/bin/yuicompressor
```

Comment: I thought that must be it, but it is still giving me the same error. Copied directly from my prod settings I now have YUI_BINARY = '/usr/bin/yui-compressor'